# Bootstrap daterangepicker with Asp.Net Textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I found a solution for using bootstrap date picker with an ASP.Net Textbox

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dp = $('#<%=DateTextbox.ClientID%>');
        dp.datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
            language: "tr"
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $(this).blur();
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
        });
});
</script>
```

However the above solution is not working for the daterangepicker I found on the following url http://mycodestock.blogspot.com/2014/01/easy-to-use-bootstrap-date-range-picker.html I edited the script to the one below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         var drp = $('#<%=selectdaterange.ClientID%>');
        drp.daterangepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
            language: "tr"
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $(this).blur();
            $(this).daterangepicker('hide');
        });
    });
```

I'm pretty new at this, is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The second set of code seems to be correct, it will be entirely dependent on which Bootstrap DateTimePicker you're using as to the structure of the JQuery.

What I believe may be the case is that you're missing either the CSS files and/or the JS file from the view. Ensure you've inserted this into either the MasterPage or the ASPX view in question.